# Re-writing Axler's Proof of an operator over a non-zero finite dimensional complex vector space $V$ having an eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prior to reading the following post please consider the following notation.

- $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ means that $T$ belongs to the set of linear operators on the vector space $V$.
- Given an operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ and a polynomial $p(z) = c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+c_mz^m$. Then $p(T)$ denotes the operator $p(T) = c_0I+c_1T+c_2T^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+c_mT^m$

In ***Linear Algebra Done Right*** Axler presents an argument to prove the following theorem

> **Theorem.** Every operator over a non-zero finite dimensional complex vector space $V$ has an eigenvalue.

He later asks the reader to re-write the argument using the linear map that sends $p\in\mathcal{P}_n(\mathbf{C})$ to $p(T)v$.

The following is my attempt at re-writing the proof.  Is it Correct? In the following Proof i make use of the well known theorem.

> (**$4.14$**) If $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{C})$ is a nonconstant polynomial, then $p$ has a unique factorization (except for the order of the factors) of the form $p(z) = c(z-\lambda_1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(z-\lambda_m)$ where $c,\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\in\mathbf{C}$.

**Proof.** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space such that $\dim V = n>0$ and let $T$ be an arbitrary linear operator on $V$. Since $V$ is non-zero we may invoke the existence of a vector $v\in V$ such that $v\neq 0$.

Consider now the map $\omega\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{P}_n(\mathbf{C}),V)$ defined such that $\omega(p) = p(T)v$, evidently $\dim\mathcal{P}_n(\mathbf{C})) = n+1$ indicating that $\omega$ is not injective, equivalently we have some non-zero polynomial $q = \alpha_0+\alpha_1z+\alpha_2z^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\alpha_mz^m$ such that $\omega(q) = q(T)v = 0$ furthermore since $q$ is non-zero it follows that not all $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ .\ .\ .\ ,\alpha_m$ equal $0$ and in particular not all of the $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ .\ .\ .  ,\alpha_m$ are $0$ since that would imply that $q(T)v = \alpha_0I = \alpha_0v = 0$ and by extension $\alpha_0 = 0$ resulting in a contradiction.

Having established that at least one of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ .\ .\ .\ ,\alpha_m$ is not zero it follows that $\deg q\ge 1$ and thus by theorem $\textbf{4.14}$ we may factorize the operator $q(T)$ to yield $q(T) = \beta(T-\lambda_1I)(T-\lambda_2I)\cdot\cdot\cdot(T-\lambda_kI)$ where $\beta\neq 0$ consequently $\beta(T-\lambda_1I)(T-\lambda_2I)\cdot\cdot\cdot(T-\lambda_kI)v = 0$ implying that at least one of the operators $(T-\lambda_1I),(T-\lambda_2I),\ .\ .\ .\ ,(T-\lambda_kI)$ is not injective therefore at least of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ .\ .\ .\ ,\alpha_k$ must be an eigenvalue of $T$.

$\blacksquare$

**PS:** Are there any proofs of the above theorem that do not make use of theorem $4.14$.

Comment: The "theorem" you mention is not very interesting: it is true whenever we have a UFD . The theorem you mention adds a critical piece of information: the factorisation is in **linear factors**, and it's in fact a rather funny way to express the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra: the complex numbers field is algebraically closed.

Comment: The proof makes some "fishy" use of the fact, unproved and unreliable thus, that to work with *usual polynomials* is the same as working with polynomial on linear maps...and this is false, as many books warn us when reading about the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem's and the almost trivial "proof" that doesn't work exactly because of the same reason. Thus, either you explain this important point or else I'd say your proof is wrong. And as far as I know there is no proof, or at least a "standard" one, that doesn't use the correct form of theorem 4.14...

Comment: Except for the missing information that the factors in the factorization have degree one, the proof is fine.

Comment: In connection with the comment above, let me note that Theorem 4.14 in my book Linear Algebra Done Right correctly states that the factors have degree one. Thus Theorem 4.14 has not been accurately quoted in the original question above.

Comment: @SheldonAxler My Apologies Good Sir i have edited the post so that it now correctly quotes theorem 4.14. Thankyou for your helpful comment.